# Regular expression class in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this regular expression below

```
^(((\s*0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]{2}))\s*)*)
```

which will accept only

```
0x12 0x34 0xA2
```

It should reject

```
0x12, 0x34
```

I am using like this,

```
if(true != Regex.IsMatch(inputData, @"^(((\s*0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]{2}))\s*)*)"))
{
Console.WriteLine("error");
}
```

But even if I give `0x12, 0x34` or any string, it is always giving true.
Can somebody solve this please? Thanks

Comment: Whats the difference between what it should accept and what is should fail? Fail is a subset of accept?!

Answer (score 4):

You're missing the `$` character at the end of your regular expression. The `$` character matches the end of the string or line. Currently, it is checking if the string begins with zero or more hexadecimal strings of the specified length. Any string will begin with at least 0 instances of the string, so all strings are currently matching.

The regular expression should look like `^(((\s*0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]{2}))\s*)*)$`.

Alternatively, if you want it to begin with at least one of those hexadecimal strings, you should replace the last `*` character with a `+`, which will match one or more instances.

That regular expression would look like `^(((\s*0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]{2}))\s*)+)$`.

Lastly, if you want the strings to be separated by spaces, you would need to modify it a bit more. Both of those regular expressions will allow consecutive strings without spaces in between. I have a feeling that the 'correct' regular expression is going to be rather ugly, so you may be better off using `String.Split` on spaces and ignoring empty lines, running the regular expression `^0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]{2})$` on each string.

Comment: The regular expression you mention would match empty lines as well which I don't the the OP wants

Comment: @T.V. I've added another regular expression that should match one or more instances, although I've now noticed that both regular expressions will accept multiple hexadecimal strings with no whitespace between them.

Answer (score 1):

You should end the regex with a `$`. Without that, it will match the number before the comma and return true. Should be like this:

```
^(((\s*0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]{2}))\s*)*)$
```

If you don't want to match blank lines, change the final `*` to a `+`:

```
^(((\s*0[xX]([0-9a-fA-F]{2}))\s*)+)$
```

Also, if you're not using the groups you can drop the most of the parentheses:

```
^(\s*0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]{2}\s*)+$
```